# Sorting Gmail Labels

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have recently added two labels and they are at the bottom of the alpha list of labels. How do I move them into the alpha ranking? I can move them below the MORE line and back up to original position but not into the alpha ranking.

Comment: you got screenshot?

Comment: What do you mean by “alpha ranking”?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Gmail labels sort](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26807/custom-gmail-labels-sort)

Answer (score 1):

- **the only way how to "sort" Gmail's labels is to rename them:**

  [image: 5]
- **to move them up into "always visible part" you need to unhide them in Settings:**

  [image: 5]