# Reorder labels order in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Is there a way to reorder labels in Gmail? There is one specific label I need to access more than the others and I would like it at the top.

I'm using Airmail 2 as my local IMAP client connected to my email running on Google Apps for Work.

Comment: See also: [How do I organize my labels in Gmail?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1915/354)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Gmail doesn't provide a way to reorder labels. They are listed in strictly alphabetical order.

What I have done is put a relatively unobtrusive punctuation character in the front of the label. For example:

- `_followup`
- `!important`
- `+client`

That way they flow to the top. You can do a similar thing to drop labels to the bottom, all depending on whether the character is sorted before or after letters.

For symbols that sort after letters, `{|}~`, (or between upper- and lower-case, `[\]^_` and ` ), see
[ASCII on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set). All the rest will sort before, matching the table ordering. This underlying bit representation gives an index number, and therefore ordering, "lexicographic", to each character.

Comment: You can also use the braille blank character "⠀", which will not be stripped by gmail and will still bring labels to the top.

Comment: Any idea what characters will drop a label to the bottom?

Comment: It sorts in lexicographic order, based on underlying byte sequence from ASCII. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set Some symbols `[\]^_\`` will be between upper and lower case, while others will sort after: `{|}~`. All the rest will sort before, matching the table ordering

Comment: Under ASCII, ! should sort before _, but as far as I can tell it sorts after.

Comment: What's really annoying about label sorting in GMail is that Unicode characters don't sort according to code!

Comment: So I tried... a lot of unicode characters. And I found a few that sort below ascii chars (although I couldn't tell what order it was in, and the vast majority of the chars I tried didn't work). Anyway, the nicest one that sorted below ascii was Ξ. Iirc the aleph character and the one that looked like sunglasses worked too, but I don't have them up anymore or I'd paste them too.

Comment: Unfortunately,  on my system (email on Google Chrome on  a Windows 10 PC)   email uses different sort orders for labels in different views.   The list of labels on the left-hand side seems to adopt ASCII sort order. The list of labels that you get when you are trying to choose a label to apply in a filter has a different sort order, as does the  list of labels that you  that when creating a new label.    this may be arising because some of these use Windows  or locale specific sorting, whereas others use ASCII sorting.

Comment: on my system right now:  list of labels in left sidebar, _   is sorted to top.  Ditto "label as", and "create new label".   But when I am creating a filter, and choose "apply the label", + Is sorted to top.   I believe there are other different sort orders as well.